# Delete hundreds of nodes by ID programmatically

Tags: 7, drush

I am trying to remove 700 or so nodes from my Drupal 7 system (they are duplicates) and have a big list of node IDs in a text file.

Have tried using [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) but it doesn't allow me to enter a list of IDs.

Also looked at using Drush documentation, but it doesn't seem to have a node-delete command? (surely a pretty standard thing?)

So now I'm thinking of writing my own **Python** script to do the following:

- Take list of input IDs (via input file)

(note: this is just pseudo code)

```
# remove nodes
Foreach id in file_in_ids:
   SQL(DELETE FROM node WHERE nid={id});

# clean up all rows in tables containing col 'entity_id':
tables_with_entity_id = SQL(SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME
IN (
'entity_id'
)
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_drupal_db')

foreach table_name in tables_with_entity_id:
  foreach id in file_in_ids:
    SQL(DELETE FROM {table_name} WHERE entity_id=id)
```

Does this seem like a sound approach?

Answer (score 6):

You want to avoid deleting directly from the database. The node system distributes its data across a number of tables. Generally you always want to use the API. The method your after is [node_delete()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete/7) which takes the nid as its single argument. This will handle deleting all the associated data and firing off any hooks that are attached to the event.

An alternative approach:

- Download and install the "Devel" module. This then gives you access to a page at /devel/php where you can run arbitrary PHP code within Drupal.
- You could write custom code to load the text file and explode the nid's into an array. Something like this:

  ```
  $nids = file_get_contents("/path/to/file"); 
  $nids = explode(",", $nids); // This will depend on how your nids are delimited. Could be line break "\n"
  foreach ($nids as $n) {
    node_delete($n);
  }
  ```

Comment: You want to make sure you run them through node_delete so that all of the hooks fire. This is a very simple example, the code might need some improving.

Comment: Drupal 7 also has node_delete_multiple()

Comment: Thanks a lot. Rather than install devel module and run node_delete() through /devel/php (I think it will time out, its a lot of nid's i'm gonna feed it), can I create a cli php script and call node_delete() within it (exactly like your code above)?

Comment: I mean this is why I'm so surprised that drush does not faciliate node-deletion?

Comment: Think I'll give this a go: http://www.zyxware.com/articles/1340/how-to-delete-nodes-in-bulk-programmatically-from-a-drupal-site

Comment: there is a drush command php-eval which allows you to run php code. For example: drush php-eval "echo 'hello';"

The only issue you might run into with your approach, or using eval is that Drupal may not be bootstrapped to the correct level and the required files may not be included. I dont think 700 will be too bad, depending on what fields are attached to your nodes.

As for drush not handling node deletion, its designed more as a sys admin tool than for content management. You could always write your own drush extension

Comment: Yep, that link you posted looks good, it includes the bootstrap so shouldnt be an issue there

Comment: Ok sweet - will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Done! The node_delete works great from clio - http://pastebin.com/SfeahGyE

Thanks Tim mate!

Comment: A command line drush based approach of the same could be - https://gist.github.com/sumeetpareek/6173667

Answer (score 2):

Use [Drush Entity](https://drupal.org/project/drush_entity) extension. It implements several operations on entities via drush. One of them is entity-delete:

```
drush entity-delete node 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Also https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_bulk_delete which doesn't have a security advisory.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here's a similar menu callback function I wrote for another developer's site which had an issue with orphaned nodes being created without a node type set:

Hat tip to MPD - I wasn't aware of node_delete_multiple() for D7 (but this was written for a D6 site anyway)

```
    function es_node_cleanup_callback() {
      // get all nodes without node type
      $q = 'select nid from {node} where type = ""';
      $r = db_query($q);
      if(!$r) {
        drupal_set_message('query failed');
      }
      else {
        $counter = 0;
        $message = 0;
        if(mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) {
          while($row = mysql_fetch_row($r)) {
            if(isset($row[0]) && ctype_digit($row[0])) {
              node_delete($row[0]);
              $counter ++;
            }
            else if($message == 0) {
              drupal_set_message(print_r($row, 1));
              $message = 1;
            }
          }
          drupal_set_message($counter . ' nodes deleted');    
        }
        else {
          drupal_set_message('No orphanned nodes');    
        }
      }

      drupal_goto('admin');
    }
```

Comment: This could be altered to use the data from the text file via file_get_contents() and then using explode() to get the nids as an array, which could then either be passed to node_delete_multiple() or iterated through...

Answer (score 1):

If they are duplicates they will have the same title, so you can views bulk operation , modify the view to search by title and delete (select all,  including all nodes not in current page matching the search). Very useful.

You'd probably could also tweak the view to add node id's...